# Imported a Python module; why does a reassigning a member in it also affect an import elsewhere?

Tags: python, import

I am seeing Python behavior that I don't understand. Consider this layout:

```
project
|   main.py
|   test1.py
|   test2.py
|   config.py
```

main.py:

```
import config as conf
import test1
import test2

print(conf.test_var)
test1.test1()
print(conf.test_var)
test2.test2()
```

test1.py:

```
import config as conf

def test1():
    conf.test_var = 'test1'
```

test2.py:

```
import config as conf

def test2():
    print(conf.test_var)
```

config.py:

```
test_var = 'initial_value'
```

so, `python main.py` produce:

```
initial_value
test1
test1
```

I am confused by the last line. I thought that it would print `initial_value` again because I'm importing `config.py` in `test2.py` again, and I thought that changes that I've made in the previous step would be overwritten. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Try a `reload(conf)` somewhere in between and note the difference. Loaded modules are cached. When you load `conf` in `test?.py`, you just get a reference to the already loaded module.

Comment: I think what the current answers are missing to state is that importing a module does not execute the script it holds; as correctly pointed out, Python caches modules.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Python caches imported modules. The second `import` call doesn't reload the file.

Comment: If you want to check, `sys.modules` contains references to all cached imports.

Comment: And reload can be done by calling `reload(conf)` for Python2 or `importlib.reload(conf)` for Python3.

Answer (score 8):

test2.py

```
import config as conf

def test2():
    print(id(conf.test_var))
    print(conf.test_var)
```

test1.py

```
import config as conf

def test1():
    conf.test_var = 'test1'
    print(id(conf.test_var))
```

Change code like this.

And run `main.py`

```
initial_value
140007892404912
test1
140007892404912
test1
```

So, you can see that in both cases you are changing value of the same variable. See these `id`'s are same.

Answer (score 4):

You edited the `test_var` in `test1.py` and then just printed it again using `test2.py`. Importing again does not change the fact than you assigned new value to the variable - it does not "reset" the value to the first one.

Answer (score 4):

You changed the value of `test_var` when you ran `test1`, and so it was already changed when you ran `test2`.

That variable will not reset for every file in which you import it.  It will be one value for everything.

Answer (score 1):

no, you're changing with `test1()` in the config.py a constant value.
This won't be resetted. Since you print it in `test2()`, the modified value gets printed again.